# xvfb-run redirects STDOUT and STDERR to STDOUT only

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redirection, xvfb

I'm trying to run an application via `xvfb-run`.  I need to access this application's STDOUT stream independently from STDERR.  Normally, I'd do something like this:

```
node script.js > output.txt
```

I then expect to see any STDERR output on the console, and any STDOUT output in `output.txt`.  This works fine.  However, when I run with `xvfb-run`:

```
xvfb-run node script.js > output.txt
```

In this case, both STDERR and STDOUT from my script are put into `output.txt`.  This is not desirable.

**How can I use `xvfb-run` without losing the ability to redirect my original STDOUT and STDERR streams?**

For reference, here's an example of a Node.js script that I'm testing with:

```
process.stdout.write('STDOUT Test Line\n');
process.stderr.write('STDERR Test Line\n');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug reported some years ago.  Editing `/usr/bin/xvfb-run` manually does indeed solve the problem.  From https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868876:

```
Removing the 2>&1 from the exec line in xfvb-run solves this.

--- /usr/bin/xvfb-run   2017-07-07 07:09:57.000000000 +0200
+++ -   2017-07-19 14:07:29.727690002 +0200
@@ -180,7 +180,7 @@
 
 # Start the command and save its exit status.
 set +e
-DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1
+DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@"
 RETVAL=$?
 set -e
```

Related Ubuntu bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1059947